# How to validate Page View on MarketingCloud Mobile Analytics

Tags: marketing-cloud

Our team is struggling to validate **Page Views** on the MarketingCloud Mobile Analytics.

**Can someone share with us how we make this validation on the Marketing Cloud?**

*We've followed the following documentation:*

*iOS:* https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/personalization-collect.html

*Android:* https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html

Thank you!

Comment: Use Status Console: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_personalization_builder_status_console.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already installed the mobile collect code as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_collect_code.htm&type=5#mc_ctc_collect_code) along with [Track Page View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_track_page_view.htm&type=5#mc_ctc_collect_code) call code. Track page view call can capture three types of information: product or content views, categories views, or search views. Now, you can use [Personalization Builder Status Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_personalization_builder_status_console.htm&type=5) to monitor incoming Collect Tracking Code data by call type.